# How to display values on the lower side of the matplotlib chart?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib

How to display values on the lower side of the matplotlib chart?

I have this

[image]

I need this [image]

Comment: [How to put the legend out of the plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4700614/how-to-put-the-legend-out-of-the-plot)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this where `blue, yellow, green, red, purple` is the lines you have

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.xlim(0, 1000)
plt.ylim(0, 5)
plt.xticks([0, 200, 400, 600, 800])
plt.yticks([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
plt.legend((blue, yellow, green, red, purple), (180, 365, 730, 1095, 1825))
plt.show()
```